# Create parent-children query from many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good day,
I struggle to create a query in Postgres to obtain a many-to-many relationship in parent-children form.
There are two tables:

1. 'Projects'
   [projects table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSXwB.png)
2. 'Services'
   [services table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODiPF.png)

They are connected with the third project_service table
[project_service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k94wm.png)

The query `SELECT projects.id_project, projects.title, projects.level, services.id_service, services.service FROM projects, services, project_service WHERE projects.id_project = project_service.id_project AND services.id_service = project_service.id_service` return this table:
[query result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mWq3.png)

How to write a query to get this table in parent-children form like this:

```
[
{ "id": "1000", "level": "Projects", "title": "Project 1", "children": [
    { "id": "2000", "service": "Service 1},
    { "id": "2001", "service": "Service 2},
    { "id": "2002", "service": "Service 3},
    { "id": "2003", "service": "Service 4}
]},

{ "id": "1001", "level": "Projects", "title": "Project 2", "children": [
    { "id": "2004", "service": "Service 5}
]}]
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements of them as **text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
 with svc_json as (
  select id_service, to_jsonb(services) as svc
    from services
), together as (
  select p.*, jsonb_agg(s.svc) as children  
    from project_service ps
    join svc_json s on s.id_service = ps.id_service
    join projects p on p.id_project = ps.id_project
   group by p.id_project, p.title, p.level
)
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(together)))
  from together;

              jsonb_pretty               
-----------------------------------------
 [                                      +
     {                                  +
         "level": "Projects",           +
         "title": "Project 1",          +
         "children": [                  +
             {                          +
                 "service": "Service 1",+
                 "id_service": 2000     +
             },                         +
             {                          +
                 "service": "Service 2",+
                 "id_service": 2001     +
             },                         +
             {                          +
                 "service": "Service 3",+
                 "id_service": 2002     +
             },                         +
             {                          +
                 "service": "Service 4",+
                 "id_service": 2003     +
             }                          +
         ],                             +
         "id_project": 1000             +
     },                                 +
     {                                  +
         "level": "Projects",           +
         "title": "Project 2",          +
         "children": [                  +
             {                          +
                 "service": "Service 5",+
                 "id_service": 2004     +
             }                          +
         ],                             +
         "id_project": 1001             +
     }                                  +
 ]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mike! The output looks exactly what I need. However, I've got an issue with using this. The result of this query is meant to be a source of data for JS script and this script fetches only JSON. As far as understand jsonb_pretty returns in JSONB format, which differs from JSON. Is there a way to convert it to JSON? Again, thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @tumanoff  Remove the call to `jsonb_pretty()`.  With or without it your javascript library should convert it to a json object automatically.  If not, it will be brought in as a string, and you can parse it in javascript.  Give it a try.

Comment: I removed `jsonb_pretty()`, but still can't make it work. Here's resultant object: `[{"jsonb_agg":[{"level":"Projects","title":"Project 1","children":[{"service":"Service 1","id_service":2000},{"service":"Service 2","id_service":2001},{"service":"Service 3","id_service":2002}],"id_project":1000},{"level":"Projects","title":"Project 2","children":[{"service":"Service 5","id_service":2004},{"service":"Service 4","id_service":2003}],"id_project":1001}]}]`. I guess the reason why it doesn't work is `[{"jsonb_agg"}]`. Is it possible to rid of this? Thank you

Comment: @tumanoff Do you honestly not know how to deal with that?

Comment: I honestly don't. Just started learning a couple of months ago.

Comment: @tumanoff  You are being tripped up by the library you are using to query the database.  It looks like you are printing the entire result set.  Whatever your variable is called, say `x`, you need to take the `jsonb_agg` key from the rows returned.  This is normally done in a loop.  If you know you are getting one row, then something like `x[0]['jsonb_agg']` should get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Yes, you're right, it's turned to be that simple `var resources = results.rows[0]['jsonb_agg']`. I wish I could hit upon this myself. Again, thanks for your support.